# How to replace whitespaces with a comma for a column of nested lists in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a df with a column of nested lists.
EG: df['list']=[['6.65539026 -1.24900830'],['6.65537977 -1.24882162'],['6.65537977 -1.24882162'],['6.65544653 -1.24888170']]

I want to transform this column to get this desired output[[6.65539026,-1.24900830],[6.65537977,-1.24882162],[6.65537977,-1.24882162],[6.65544653,-1.24888170]]

Basically removing the quotes around the nested lists and replacing the spaces in between with a comma.

Comment: The nested list represents one row in the column.

Comment: This answer solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/67791399/16096319

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list':[[['6.65539026 -1.24900830'],['6.65537977 -1.24882162'],['6.65537977 -1.24882162'],['6.65544653 -1.24888170']]]})

df['list'].explode(ignore_index=True).str[0].str.split()
```

Output:

```
0    [6.65539026, -1.24900830]
1    [6.65537977, -1.24882162]
2    [6.65537977, -1.24882162]
3    [6.65544653, -1.24888170]
Name: list, dtype: object
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'list':[['6.65539026 -1.24900830'],['6.65537977 -1.24882162'],['6.65537977 -1.24882162'],['6.65544653 -1.24888170']]})

df['list_new'] = df['list'].str[0].str.strip('\[|\]').str.split(' ')
```

Output:

```
                       list                   list_new
0  [6.65539026 -1.24900830]  [6.65539026, -1.24900830]
1  [6.65537977 -1.24882162]  [6.65537977, -1.24882162]
2  [6.65537977 -1.24882162]  [6.65537977, -1.24882162]
3  [6.65544653 -1.24888170]  [6.65544653, -1.24888170]
```

---

Comment: Tried this. it says "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: @JL233 run these two lines alone?  Does it work?  Maybe your input dataframe is a slightly different structure.

Comment: Boston. Yes it does. However, the dataset is supposed to be nested. The list example i gave represented one row in the dataframe. Every row in the column contains a nested list

Comment: Okay, can you create and example that mimics two or three rows of you actual dataframe?   This will give me the correct structure so I can get you a solution.